# How to read list of 3rd party resources held in jar files from Android Application at runtime

Tags: android, classpath

Im investigating the use of `citeproc` in my current Android application

```
api 'de.undercouch:citeproc-java:2.0.0'
implementation 'org.citationstyles:styles:20.11'
implementation 'org.citationstyles:locales:20.11'
```

Its working fine using

```
   // https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eclipsesource/j2v8/j2v8/6.2.0/
    implementation(name: 'j2v8-6.2.0', ext: 'aar')
```

However as Im running on Android OS the CSL static method

```
CSL.getSupportedStyles()
```

returns an empty list.

the underlying code in this method is as follows:-

```
private static Set<String> getAvailableFiles(String prefix,
        String knownName, String extension) throws IOException {
    Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // first load a file that is known to exist
    String name = prefix + knownName + "." + extension;
    URL knownUrl = CSL.class.getResource("/" + name);
    if (knownUrl != null) {
        String path = knownUrl.getPath();
        // get the jar file containing the file
        if (path.endsWith(".jar!/" + name)) {
            String jarPath = path.substring(0, path.length() - name.length() - 2);
            URI jarUri;
            try {
                jarUri = new URI(jarPath);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // ignore
                return result;
            }
            try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(new File(jarUri))) {
                Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip.entries();
                while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    ZipEntry e = entries.nextElement();
                    if (e.getName().endsWith("." + extension) &&
                            (prefix.isEmpty() || e.getName().startsWith(prefix))) {
                        result.add(e.getName().substring(
                                prefix.length(), e.getName().length() - 4));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to list get `getAvailableFiles` method to work on Android OS?

The following aproach does not work

```
   val name: String = "$prefix$knownName.$extension"
   val knownUrl: URL? = CSL::class.java.classLoader.getResource("$name")
```

All I require is the list of "`.csl`" files that in an Eclipse java project show as residing in `styles-20.11.jar` file

When I extract my Application APK file the "`.csl`" files are all listed seperately

Where am I going wrong?

How can I get a list of all "`.csl`" files available to CSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided detail guides me to find the solution. That's enough to define `apk` in the checker condition.

```
class CLSHelper {

    public static Set<String> getSupportedStyles() throws IOException {
        return getAvailableFiles("", "ieee", "csl");
    }

    /**
     * Customizing this function to able run in Android environment
     */
    private static Set<String> getAvailableFiles(String prefix,
                                                 String knownName, String extension) throws IOException {
        Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        // first load a file that is known to exist
        String name = prefix + knownName + "." + extension;
        URL knownUrl = CSL.class.getResource("/" + name);
        if (knownUrl != null) {
            String path = knownUrl.getPath();
            // get the jar or apk file containing the file
            if (path.endsWith(".jar!/" + name) || path.endsWith(".apk!/" + name)) { // changing this line
                String jarPath = path.substring(0, path.length() - name.length() - 2);
                URI jarUri;
                try {
                    jarUri = new URI(jarPath);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // ignore
                    return result;
                }
                try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(new File(jarUri))) {
                    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip.entries();
                    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                        ZipEntry e = entries.nextElement();
                        if (e.getName().endsWith("." + extension) &&
                                (prefix.isEmpty() || e.getName().startsWith(prefix))) {
                            result.add(e.getName().substring(
                                    prefix.length(), e.getName().length() - 4));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
CSL.getSupportedStyles()        // []
CLSHelper.getSupportedStyles()  // [dependent/annals-of-occupational-and-environmental-medicine, dependent/photoacoustics, dependent/statistical-science, twentieth-century-music, dependent/aims-medical-science, dependent/cell-systems, dependent/nursingplus-open, dependent/computer-science-review,...]
```

P.S: To running on AndroidStudio I had to add these lines in `build.gradle`

```
android{
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/truffle/language'
    }
}
```

Comment: nice work, I was very close, you earned the bounty though